# how to reply to a blind reviewer?

Tags: publications, peer-review, editors

I have a paper under review. Two of the reviewers have accepted the paper. The third reviewer is ......This is the first time that I met such a blind reviewer. Most of his questions are superficial and they have answers in my paper. It is just his careless review that makes him did not find it. For example, he asked me where the shear stress is measure. However, the definition is just in the text and the Table. In another Table, I compare my date with others and I just call my date as "present". This is very common and the author's study is always called as "present". But he did not find it and asked me aggressively that why there is no date of mine in that Table... He asked me why I just present others' date without mine. Also, he criticizes me that the error in a Figure is 10MPa... Dear God, please give him a new pair of eyes. The error is not as big as 10MPa. He just match the wrong date. He may compare my date in a position with the reference date in another position. Also, he forces me to cite papers......I just sent emails and complain about the reviewer 3. I also ask whether it is possible to accept the paper by finding one more reviewer(If 3 accept and 1 reject, I feel this is more convincing...) However, When I contact with the EIC, the editor told me that:
Once I have such request again, he will reject my paper....
That is all his reply. Nothing else... He did not even go into this issue and just conclude that.....
My advisor just asked me to bear it. But I just try to find some support here. I have publicized 6 journal papers (IF 2-4) and I am a PhD student in Aerospace. My research is finite element methods. Thank you.

Comment: Just write him what you explained in your question but in a formal way. This would be enough.

Comment: Thank you, John. It seems that this is the only thing I can do. The reviewer is so impolite. He uses a lot of "!!!!!!!!!!" in his review comments and his words are very aggressive.

Comment: You use a lot of ....

Comment: I never do so in a formal review comments...

Comment: I feel much better now after nearly one hour's anger and I will go back to revise my paper. Thanks for reading. I never predicted that someday I will be such negative. When I publicized my previous 5-6 papers, I all felt very happy. This is the first time that the anger dominates me in dealing with a paper.

Comment: You may want to go through your question and fix the use of the word "date" -- I'm pretty sure you mean "data", which is something different altogether.

Comment: Yes, it's a typo for an angry man. However, many people here just assume that it is my poor paper writing that causes this problem even if they did not read my paper. First, my advisor is a very good professor in the top 10 universities in USA. He gave me a lot of revisions before we submit the paper. Second, my paper is not written by "English". A mathematician write papers by equations and few English. So you know, those people with general beautiful positive words below may know nothing about a math paper...But people love those sentences. That makes them cool.

Answer (score 6):

I get frustrated too if a paper is poorly written or does not follow 'standard' convention.   There are no 'blind reviewers, assuming the venue is reputable.  You only have reviewers who gave up on your paper because it is poor or not interesting or things that should be there are not there.   Other things that annoy me are grammar mistakes, and poor writing practices.

Now calm down.  Let it sit for a while.  After you are rational, then revise your paper accordingly.  Address the reviewer's comments and make it clearer.  Ask yourself, why did the reviewer get frustrated at this point?  Presentation errors are the easiest to fix.  Try addressing comments that ask you to prove X is true, and your only answer is, I'm not smart enough!

Comment: Thanks for such a positive answer and people love positive things, instead of negative truth. I know how to do it. I explain everything in details politely in my response to review comments. Why I say these here? I just want to vent my anger and then go back to revise my paper...